# Using dp for same dimension is not working for different phones of different resolutions but same dimention

Tags: android, responsive-design, screen-orientation, screen-resolution, screen-size

I am working on an app which must support all the sizes. Since the 1920x1080 is wider than 480x800, I am unable to give the best fit for both at same time for landscape view. Where as they lie under same dimension. There is no problem with the portrait view cause it has really a small amount of difference on portrait view but when turning it to landscape view the entire thing is not coming in the screen.

This is the view of 1920x1080.

[image]

This is the view of 480x800

[image]

Both these sizes are accessing their xml file from layout-sw320dp-land

I'm only facing this problem for hdp screens that is layout-sw320dp screens since it has a very small space to work with. And there is no such problem for higher screen sizes since we have enough space to decorate.

Can anyone help me to sort out this problem?

We have many questions and answers for this problem but I'm unable to get the perfect solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make your view's latout_height = "match_parent" to fill the available space

Comment: did you try "Available screen height h<N>dp " modificator?

Comment: no @aelimill I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: and @pskink I have used `centerVertical="true"` rather `height="math_parent"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me more than perfect. `layout-sw320dp-land-hdpi` and `layout-sw320dpi-land-xhdpi`

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem only happens in this screen consider using LinearLayout with weights, that will give you a responsive design that is independent from the screen size or resolution - instead it will render by percentage making the views take the same percentage of the screen no matter what the screen size is.

Attached is an XML sample for a weighted screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:background="#8000ff00"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- This is the green view -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#80ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <!-- This is the red view -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="#800000ff" >

        <!-- This is the bottom blue view -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was thinking about the view stuff but as I'm a newbie in android I don't know how to use it perfectly. Can you give me the basic idea about view and percentage?

Comment: I added something that might fit for your needs, you can switch the linearlayout with the color to be other layouts and play with their weight.
For more info please see this post - http://android.amberfog.com/?p=328

Comment: Something worked for me more than perfect. `layout-sw320dp-land-hdpi` and `layout-sw320dpi-xhdpi`